# Populating two UITableViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

Ok a little background so you will get what I'm trying to do here. There will be a few  questions so please bear with me.

Im building my own iPhone application that displays the upcoming games for current day. You can see the structure on the image below.

[image]

Lets call the upper Table View: "TableView1" and the one blow it "TableView2".
As of right now I'm populating the data for TableView1 from a website that returns Json text.

http://afternoon-springs-7986.herokuapp.com

And here is the code that does it in GamesInfoViewController.m (the class that is connected to TableView1 through Storyboard)

```
- (void) retrieveData{

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:5000"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    GamesInfoArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];





    for (int i= 0; i < jsonArray.count; i++)
    {
        NSString *gameTime = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"time"];
        NSString *gameID = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"identity"];
        NSString *homeTeam = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"homeTeam"];
        NSString *homeScore = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"homeScore"];
        NSString *awayTeam = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"awayTeam"];
        NSString *awayScore = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"awayScore"];

        [GamesInfoArray addObject:[[GameInfo alloc] initWithidentity:gameID andtime:gameTime andawayTeam:awayTeam andawayScore:awayScore andhomeTeam:homeTeam andhomeScore:homeScore]]; 
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

As you can see i am saving the information in NSMutableArray called GamesInfoArray. Now some of the objects stored in GamesInfoArray will be used to populate TableView2 (i will make an if statement to check if a particular game has started using the time value stored in each object)

Im thinking the best way to do this is to take this code above that gets the information from the web server and put it in a new class that handles that information and then puts the information in two different NSMutableArrays. The one i got right now and another one to populate TableView2. So that each TableView can get the information that they need from the correct NSMutableArray.

This is an example of TableView1:

[image]

The ones you see that has a green button means its live and that is an example of an object that would be shown in TableView2

Since its my first app and i have never done anything like this before i would love some tips if I'm thinking right or if i should do it another way.

If you need anything extra code or information just tell me and ill update the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since TableView2 relies on information from GamesInfoViewController it makes sense to create a separate class to store the data. Especially since you can't rely that TableView2 will have up to date data if it's being retrieved in GamesInfoViewController.

I would create two classes: an API client class which fetches the data, and a singleton which stores/caches the GameInfo object array. I would only store the GameInfo objects on the singleton and have a separate array on the datasource TableView2 if required (if you're showing the exact same information you could except only live games you can just share the same GameInfo array between the two tables). The retrieveData method should also stay in each of your view controller classes so that you can appropriately respond to connection/parsing errors.

Comment: I would use retreiveData in each view controller to get the information from the singleton class then right? @psobko

Comment: I would use retrieveData to pull live data from the server/check how long it's been since you've received fresh data. That way if there's any errors pulling the data from the server you can decide how the app should proceed.